# 404 error while mocking server using restito

Tags: mocking, rest-assured

I had written a simple rest service and then tried to test it by creating stub server through restito and call the service using rest-assured. While running the junit test on the test class I get assertion error that response returned with status 404 instead of 200.

When I test the same Rest Service by starting a local server (tomcat in my case) it returns the response successfully.

Below is my code:

**CxfRestService.java**

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


@Path("/")
@WebService(name = "employeeService")
public interface CxfRestService {

@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path("/getemployeedetail")
public Response getEmployeeDetail(
        @QueryParam("employeeId") String employeeId);

}
```

**CxfRestServiceImpl.java**

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.kronos.cxfrestservice.CxfRestService;
import com.kronos.cxfrestservice.dao.EmployeeDao;

public class CxfRestServiceImpl implements CxfRestService {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDao employeeDao;

    @Override
    public Response getEmployeeDetail(String employeeId) {
        if ("0".equalsIgnoreCase(employeeId)) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(employeeDao.getEmployeeDetails(employeeId)).build();
    }
}
```

**CxfRestServiceTest.java**

```
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import com.jayway.restassured.response.Response;
import com.xebialabs.restito.server.StubServer;

public class CxfRestServiceTest {

    private StubServer stubServer;

    @Before
    public void start() {
        stubServer = new StubServer().run();
        RestAssured.port = stubServer.getPort();
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost";
        RestAssured.basePath = "/CxfRestService/rest/employeeservices";
    }

    @After
    public void stop() {
        if (stubServer != null) {
            stubServer.stop();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetEmployeeDetail() {

        Response response = given().param("employeeId", "1").when()
            .get("/getemployeedetail");

        String responseData = response.getBody().asString();
        assertEquals("Response should be valid for employee id other than 0",
            Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

**beans.xml**

```
<jaxrs:server id="employeeService" address="/employeeservices">
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="cxfServiceImpl" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
    </jaxrs:server>

   <bean id="cxfServiceImpl" class="com.kronos.cxfrestservice.internal.CxfRestServiceImpl"/>
   <bean id="employeeDao" class="com.kronos.cxfrestservice.dao.EmployeeDao"/>
```

In **web.xml** the CXFServlet mapped to url-pattern /rest/*.

I am very new in this field so please suggest me what I may be doing wrong here or missing something.

Thanks

Comment: What you did here is start a Restito server without any stubbed methods, then you try connecting to it on the path /CxfRestService/rest/employeeservices. This path is not stubbed so it will return 404 since there is no matching stubbing conditions.

You cannot use Restito to test your Server code, you're currently testing Restito with RestAssured.